# Font styles in CSS

Tags: html, css, fonts

I'm taking on a site and am tasked with reviewing the CSS, making CSS updates where necessary, and finally making content updates. While working on making a style change to an H1 tag, I noticed the .fontXlarge class has the styling that would work perfectly, however it doesn't apply to an "H1" tag. It only applies to p, span, ol li and ul li.

Here are the font styles. For this example, I only included the styling for .fontXlarge:

```
/* Mobile first */
.fontXlarge p,
.fontXlarge span,
.fontXlarge ol li,
.fontXlarge ul li {
  color: #a9a9a9;
  font-family: "Brand Times", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 18px;
}

.fontLarge p,
.fontLarge span,
.fontLarge ol li,
.fontLarge ul li { }

.fontMedium p,
.fontMedium span,
.fontMedium ol li,
.fontMedium ul li { }

.fontSmall p,
.fontSmall span,
.fontSmall ol li,
.fontSmall ul li { }

/* Tablet */
.fontXlarge p,
.fontXlarge span,
.fontXlarge ol li,
.fontXlarge ul li {
  font-size: 32px;
}

/* Desktop */
.fontXlarge p,
.fontXlarge span,
.fontXlarge ol li,
.fontXlarge ul li {
  font-size: 48px;
}
```

Wouldn't it make more sense to simply use the following? This seems so obvious to me that I'm wondering if I'm missing something.

```
/* Mobile first */
.fontXlarge {
  color: #a9a9a9;
  font-family: "Brand Times", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 18px;
}

/* Tablet */
.fontXlarge {
  color: #a9a9a9;
  font-family: "Brand Times", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 32px;
}

/* Desktop */
.fontXlarge {
  color: #a9a9a9;
  font-family: "Brand Times", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 48px;
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: `.<class> <element>` {display:block;}is like saying:  `apply {display:block;} to all elements of <element> type that are nested inside of the element with class <.class>`. So if you dont want that css to be applied to only the elements nested within the elements with class `fontXlarge` then go with the latter css.  Though if this is a group project be weary about changing CSS properties like this.  There could be unseen applications another developer used that type of CSS nesting for.

Comment: You can do the same with nested classes like `.class .class1 .class2 td`

Comment: Why not just go `h1 { }` directly? Do you want different `h1` styles per size? If so, create them manually.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you wanted to restrict those classes to only be usable on those specific elements, I see no reason to structure it like that. That isn't DRY. A better alternative is to just only use those classes in cases when you need them, instead of restricting the class's functionality. I would think that is just poor code.

The only other possible exception I can think of is if you need to target an element even more specifically by targetting both the element and the class, in order to override other stylings.

Using the latter code snippet looks like the better option, just make sure changing that doesn't affect the way elements are being targetted.

Comment: I believe you're agreeing with me and to use the simpler code I have at the end of my original post. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes. Sorry, that was a little unclear. I edited my answer to convey that.

Answer (score 1):

From the font styling you have given as an example, No where does it mean that **.fontXlarge** class has style for **h1.** It only means, when a parent has a class of **.fontXlarge** having children as **p**, **span**, **ol li**, **ul li**, that **font-size** would be **18px**.

```
.fontXlarge p,
.fontXlarge span,
.fontXlarge ol li,
.fontXlarge ul li {
  color: #a9a9a9;
  font-family: "Brand Times", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 18px;
}
```

What you can do is make own style something like.

```
/* Desktop */
.fontXlarge h1 { // Now it means h1 within **.fontXlarge**
  color: #a9a9a9;
  font-family: "Brand Times", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 48px;
}
```

Or if you want to directly apply **.fontXlarge** class on **h1** (if your project allows you to do that, then you can use:

```
/* Desktop */
.fontXlarge { // Now it means h1 within **.fontXlarge**
  color: #a9a9a9;
  font-family: "Brand Times", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 48px;
}
```

In which case your HTML would be something like:

```
<h1 class="fontXlarge">Test Heading</h1>
```